# Join String list elements with a delimiter in one step

Tags: java

Is there a function like join that returns List's data as a string of
all the elements, joined by delimiter provided?

```
 List<String> join; ....
 String join = list.join('+");
 // join == "Elem 1+Elem 2";
```

or one must use an iterator to manually glue the elements?

Answer (score 155):

Java 8...

```
String joined = String.join("+", list);
```

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-

Comment: Sadly `String.join()` accepts only `Iterable<CharSequence>` (apart from varargs) unlike  Guava's `Joiner.join()` which accepts `Iterable<?>`, `Iterator<?>`, varargs, ...

Comment: Correct - String.join() does not handle arbitrary types. It expects an iterable CharSequence, ie List<String>. 
If you want to delimit arbitrary types then you need to extract the String value and build the delimited list.
This is also a one liner in Java 8: `String joined = iterableOfNonCharSequence.stream().map(object -> object.methodToGetStringValue()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));`

Comment: StringJoiner is also a useful class for joining content. Here is an example program showing StringJoiner and Collectors.joining... http://pastebin.com/i2YwJcZy#

Comment: native java solutions > all

Comment: @gahrae: can you please put your stream related solution in a separate answer? I would like to vote for it :)

Comment: @iuzuz: The question has been closed so no new answers can be given. Thanks though :-)

Answer (score 100):

You can use the [`StringUtils.join()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join(byte[],%20char)) method of Apache Commons Lang:

```
String join = StringUtils.join(joinList, "+");
```

Comment: Of course, creating an utility class is also really easy, if you don't want to use a third-party library for that. But `Apache Commons Lang` provide many usefull methods, that takes care of `null` values...

Answer (score 19):

Or [Joiner](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) from Google Guava.

```
Joiner joiner = Joiner.on("+");
String join = joiner.join(joinList);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use : `org.springframework.util.StringUtils`;

```
String stringDelimitedByComma = StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString(myList);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spring you can use `StringUtils.join()` method which also allows you to specify prefix and suffix.

```
String s = StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(fieldRoles.keySet(),
                "\n", "<value>", "</value>");
```

Comment: This can actually be copied and it is a single method: https://gist.github.com/Zhuinden/5d88caee5e184e2b6d5ced329618f086

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to log the list of elements, you can use the list toString() method which already concatenates all the list elements.