# Join all but first elements in a list to string

Tags: java

Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021851/join-string-list-elements-with-a-delimiter-in-one-step) on how to join a list into a `String`,

I'm wondering what the most succinct way to drop an element from the list and then join the remaining list.  For example, if my list is:

```
[a, b, c, d]
```

and I want the `String`:

```
"bcd"
```

How could I most succinctly drop a and then join the remaining elements?  I'm new to Java, and my solutions feel heavy-handed.

Comment: in Groovy: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'][1..-1].join()`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're using java8 I like using streaming and the available collectors:

```
String result = list.stream().skip(1).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very pretty.  Hmm, on my corporate box, I'm stuck with java 7 :(

Comment: Well, you should probably use some library that has a `StringUtils` equivalent. Or just write your own function using a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] data = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
String[] f = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 1, 4);
String r = Arrays.toString(f).substring(1).replaceAll("\\]$", "").replaceAll(", ", "");
```

It does the job with Java 6 and without any library.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to drop another element like first, or more elements ,you can do
 it with filter. It is very universal way in my opinion.

```
    String [] array = {"a","b","c","d", "a"};
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
    String result = list.stream().filter(element -> !element.equals("a")).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    String result2 = Arrays.stream(array).filter(element -> !element.equals("a")).collect(Collectors.joining(","));

    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println(result2);
```

Comment: Is this also Java 8 only?

Comment: unfortunately yes, It is only in Java 8

Comment: What about Arrays.stream()

Comment: Arrays.stream() is also in Java 8 only.